# Build.xml for jsf 2.0 with weblogic 12c

Tags: jsf-2

I am new to jsf and jsp.
I know weblogic 12 c comes with jsf 2.0 but when ever i try to deloy my application, i got an stack error., i guess this is due to my build.xml which can not get my jars and wars from weblogic server,
Below is the code of build.xml,please help me asap, will be very thankful.

```
<property name="weblogic.home" value="/bea/wlserver_12.1/"/>
    <path id="WebLogic System Libraries.libraryclasspath">
        <pathelement location="../../../../bea/wlserver_12.1/server/lib/api.jar"/>
        <pathelement location="../../../../bea/wlserver_12.1/server/lib/wls-api.jar"/>
     <pathelement location="../../../../bea/wlserver_12.1/common/deployable-libraries/jsf-2.0.war"/>
  <pathelement location="../../../../bea/wlserver_12.1/common/deployable-libraries/jstl-1.2.war"/>

     </path>
   <path id="Security_Search.classpath">
        <pathelement location="build/classes"/>
        <path refid="WebLogic System Libraries.libraryclasspath"/>
       </path>

    <target name="init"> 
        <mkdir dir="build/classes"/> 
        <mkdir dir="dist" /> 
    </target>

    <path id="compile.classpath"> 
     <fileset dir="${weblogic.home}/common/deployable-libraries">
          <include name="*.war"/>
        </fileset>
        <pathelement location="../../../../bea/wlserver_12.1/common/deployable-libraries/jsf-2.0.war"/>

    </path>

    <target name="compile" depends="init" > 
        <javac destdir="build/classes" debug="true" srcdir="src"> 
            <classpath refid="compile.classpath"/> 
        </javac> 
    </target>

    <target name="war" depends="compile"> 
        <war destfile="dist/security_Search_JSF.war" webxml="WebContent/WEB-INF/web.xml"> 
            <fileset dir="WebContent">
                <exclude name="*.jar"/>
                    </fileset> 

            <classes dir="build/classes"/> 
        </war> 
    </target>

    <target name="clean">
        <delete dir="dist" />
        <delete dir="build/classes"/>
    </target>

     <target name="build"/>


</project>
```

TTP:101064][WebAppModule(security_Search_JSF:security_Search_JSF.war)] Error parsing descriptor in Web appplication "C:\bea_deploy\security_Search_JSF.war" weblogic.application.ModuleException: VALIDATION PROBLEMS WERE FOUND problem: cvc-complex-type.2.3: Element 'weblogic-web-app@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app' with element-only content type cannot have text content.: at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.loadDescriptor(WebAppModule.java:1494) at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.init(WebAppModule.java:253) at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.init(WebAppModule.java:636) at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ScopedModuleDriver.init(ScopedModuleDriver.java:162) at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper.init(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:74) at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.init(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:84) at weblogic.application.internal.flow.InitModulesFlow.initModule(InitModulesFlow.java:312) at weblogic.application.internal.flow.InitModulesFlow.initModules(InitModulesFlow.java:325) at weblogic.application.internal.flow.InitModulesFlow.prepare(InitModulesFlow.java:378) at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment$1.next(BaseDeployment.java:706) at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:35) at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment.prepare(BaseDeployment.java:237) at weblogic.application.internal.SingleModuleDeployment.prepare(SingleModuleDeployment.java:48) at weblogic.application.internal.DeploymentStateChecker.prepare(DeploymentStateChecker.java:158) at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.AppContainerInvoker.prepare(AppContainerInvoker.java:60) at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.createAndPrepareContainer(ActivateOperation.java:207) at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.doPrepare(ActivateOperation.java:96) at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.prepare(AbstractOperation.java:229) at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleDeploymentPrepare(DeploymentManager.java:747) at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.prepareDeploymentList(DeploymentManager.java:1216) at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handlePrepare(DeploymentManager.java:250) at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentServiceDispatcher.prepare(DeploymentServiceDispatcher.java:159) at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.doPrepareCallback(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:171) at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.access$000(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:13) at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer$1.run(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:46) at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl$WorkAdapterImpl.run(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:545) a
now i am getting this error.. please help,,,,
Its error in weblogic.. please

Comment: any book about jsf2.0 with weblogic would be useful.. too thanks

Comment: avax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponseWrapper.addHeader(HttpServletResponseWrapper.java:200 now i am getting this error!!! please help me please Balusc

Answer (score 0):

About the original error, it states that your **weblogic.xml** file has an invalid format.

Here's a sample of a valid weblogic.xml that references the JSF 2.0 shared library you want to use:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wls:weblogic-web-app xmlns:wls="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app/1.4/weblogic-web-app.xsd">
<wls:weblogic-version>12.1.1</wls:weblogic-version>
<wls:context-root>store</wls:context-root>
<wls:library-ref>
    <wls:library-name>jsf</wls:library-name>
    <wls:specification-version>2.0</wls:specification-version>
    <wls:exact-match>true</wls:exact-match>
</wls:library-ref>
```

If you already solved this error, please provide details on the next one - is it happening during deployment? Can you print the whole stacktrace?

Cheers,
Fabio